# Matlab - transform continuous data to discrete data

Tags: matlab, statistics

Are there any techniques which are applied for transforming continuous data to discrete data?

By continuous data I am referring to output values generated by various functions. For example the value generated for entropy for different sets of data points.

If so, are there implementations available in Matlab of Mathworks File Exchange?

Comment: To clarify: are you asking about quantisation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more precise answer is that you need to bin your data.  This can be done with arbitrary splits or splits based on quantiles of the data itself.  The base Matlab system provides support for quantiles (`quantile`) and you can watch a video on binning @ http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/01/07/binning-data-in-matlab/.  In fact, that was inspired by another SO question.

Update: I forgot to mention that histograms (`hist`) will also bin the data.  Personally, I have found that tbe binning in R (a major statistical environment) is preferable, especially using Freedman-Diaconis binning (i.e. the `breaks = "FD"` option in R for `hist`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - [sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28signal_processing%29).  This typically happens at the point of data-acquisition though - how can you have continuous data in Matlab?  (I suppose one exception would be evaluating a function for discrete input points.)

If you need a more specific answer, you'll need to edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: No offense, but sampling is not the same as binning or discretization, except to electrical engineers.  The OP didn't mention signal processing, just data.  Unfortunately, sampling is an overloaded concept by DSPers - see also this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29

Comment: Sorry to seem pedantic, but a clarification may help.  "Continuous" in the OP's sense seems to mean the data comes from the set of real numbers rather than a finite set of discrete values.  The DSP interpretation is, if I'm not mistaken, that continuous means a stream, i.e. continuously *sampled* from the statistical perspective.  And I agree - that's rather hard to do in Matlab.  :)

Comment: @Iterator: Then it depends on what the OP means by "continuous" and "discrete"...  I'm understanding it to mean e.g. a continuous time-series (in which case "sampling" in the EE sense is the correct concept).  If he means something else (e.g. quantisation), then he needs to clarify, I think.

Comment: @Iterator: Oh, I see you'veadded the "statistics" tag which wasn't there previously.  Are you sure the OP is referring to a stats problem?

Comment: I am now.  :)  To be honest, the question struck me as a general data question simply because the OP only mentioned "data".  For a continuous data stream, I'd love to see that one addressed.  :)