# is there a discretized method available in matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, neural-network

I have a set attributes like so in my data file:
[image]

The selected attributes consists of both discrete and continuous attribute types. The attributes Protocol Type and Service are of type discrete and the attribute Src Bytes, Dst Bytes, Count are of continuous type.

I want to try implement the k-means/fcm algorithm for clustering trainning data for a Neural Network, but i have to process the dataset in number of iterations, the continuous type attribute will increase the load on the algorithm and thereby decreasing the performance. Hence they are converted to discrete values but how can I achieve this in matlab?

I also need help on understanding discrete and continuous and why or how the algorithms mentioned use them?

Comment: Note that the k-means algorithm (well, Lloyd's algorithm for the k-means problem) is almost already implemented in one of matlab's toolboxes, and in many free software packages.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013913/matlab-transform-continuous-data-to-discrete-data

Comment: Your edit - asking for help on understanding discrete v. continuous, is really better as a separate question.  It's also probable that that is better for statistics.SE, though it depends if you want to know statistical reasons for discretization or algorithmic implications of discretization.  Algorithmic implications are not usually the driving factor.

Comment: Why do you think that continuous types will "increase the load on the algorithm"? k-means is efficient for continuous attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab uses double floating point precision by default.  I don't think there's significant improvement performing integer arithmetic using Matlab's interpreter (using integer data types might actually be slower because Matlab's functions are optimized for doubles).

Code up your algorithm without worrying about optimizing, then if it's too slow use the profiler to find which parts of your algorithm are slow.